# Elastic beanstalk running Node.js script as root

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node.js script/app that I am trying to run on AWS Elastic beanstalk node.js service.

The script runs fine on a local machine, after launching it with sudo.  So in moving it to the AWS elastic beanstalk environment it appears that is not running with root permissions.

Is there a way to setup a node.js script to launch with sudo, or root permissions on an elastic beanstalk server?

Comment: Is it really necessary? To launch with sudo?

Comment: I'm with André on this. Do not run your app as sudo. What is the app doing? I'm voting this down as it is bad practice.

Comment: @Clarkie - I am a newbie with node.js, and am trying to utilize some already available code, so don't know why it is requiring to run as root.  I will reexamine the code and try to understand if there is a better approach.  It is good feedback to know this is bad practice.  Would be great if you could also elaborate as to why in your opinion it is bad practice?

Comment: The root user (or sudo) has complete control over the server. By running your app as root you are allowing it complete control; imagine a really nasty person got control of your app. E.g. your app allows uploading of files and someone uploads some js files with some nasty bits of code in there...

Answer (score 2):

This is a very bad practice, so I have never tried to do it.

If you don't have any other solution, try changing your start script inside package.json, like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "sudo node index.js"
 }
```

You should add nodejs user as sudo, also. Create a file rootaccess.config inside [.ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) folder (located at app root), with this content:

```
container_commands:
  01_enable_rootaccess:
    command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
```

Remember that you should indent this .config file using spaces rather than tabs

Comment: Thank you so much, finally found this after so many hours...